# Irreducible modules - semisimple algebras and endomorphism rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional, semi-simple $k$-algebra  and $V$ and irreducible $A$-module. I am trying to prove the following claim:

> If $B = \text{End}_A(V^{\oplus r})$ then $$W = \text{Hom}_A(V,V^{\oplus r})$$ is an irreducible $B$-module, with respect to the action $(bf)(v):= bf(v)$.

I've read a proof of the claim but all it says is that $B$ acts as the full endomorphism algebra of $W.$  I don't fully understand this.  It seems like $W$ can be thought of as column vectors of maps and $B$ can be thought of as matrices, but I can't seem to make this rigorous in a way that proves $W$ is irreducible.

Any hints, suggestions, or answers are welcome!

Comment: You are quite right: since $V$ is irreducible, $B$ is just a matrix algebra of rank $r$ over $End_A(V)$, the irreducible modules of a matrix algebra are its columns.